# InStr for array of values (Possible?)

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim WBname As String
WBname = ThisWorkbook.name

If Not InStr(WBname, "test") > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("NotOK")
End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** For more clarification.

I now test if "Test" is in the Workbook name.

But I want to test if more words than just "Test" are in the Workbook name without copy-pasting the code a thousand times.

Comment: You can use Range.Find to see if the string is on the sheet.  Or you can use Join() to join the array into one string from which you can use Instr to check.  I believe the Range.Find method will be quicker.

Comment: *a whole list of strings that are not defined in the spreadsheets.*  - Are you saying that you need to test if one (or more) of several isolated string values  are in the workbook name? And what does *not defined in the spreadsheets* mean?

Comment: Clarified the post. Sorry.

Comment: Reading the edit it seems as if you want to test if worksheet names contain test. I'd suggest you iterate through thisworkbook.worksheets, If you want to test an array of values against the name then put them in an array and do a nested loop.

Comment: I've been looking at this and keep wondering about the `If Not`. Is it that there are lots of words to check for (such as "Test") and you have to have ONE of them in the Workbook name? As it stands you get the "NotOK" message box if the Workbook name DOESN'T contain "Test".

Comment: ("InStr: Returns an integer specifying the start position of the first occurrence of one string within another") If the Workbook name does not contain test, it will not be able to return a positive value and instead return 0, meaning that if not the InStr return is positive, then it spawns the msgbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this if `WBname` must contain all words

```
Dim WBname As String
WBname = ThisWorkbook.Name

Dim arrWords As Variant, aWord As Variant
arrWords = Array("aa", "bb", "cc") 'input your words list here

For Each aWord In arrWords
    If Not InStr(WBname, aWord) > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("NotOK")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Use this if `WBname` must contain at least one word

```
Dim WBname As String
WBname = ThisWorkbook.Name

Dim arrWords As Variant, aWord As Variant
arrWords = Array("aa", "bb", "cc") 'input your words list here

Dim wordFound As Boolean
wordFound = False
For Each aWord In arrWords
    If InStr(WBname, aWord) > 0 Then
        wordFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not wordFound Then
    MsgBox ("NotOK")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AND in the IF :

```
If Not InStr(WBname, "test") > 0 and not InStr(WBname, "other word") ...
```

or you can use OR, depending on your test.

Comment: I think it's nothing wrong. But maybe the OP has more than 2 or 3 words to test which makes this approach a bit cumbersome. I think that is what the OP meant with "*without copy-pasting the code a thousand times*". Maybe that's why it got voted down. Don't take it personally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No!! I don't take it personally!! In my case, I thinked that  bubububub did not want to copy the same "if...end if" more times, so it was the fast isea I had to use operators AND or OR..

Answer (score 0):

Shorter and a bit slower method with Excel Formulas:

```
containsAny = Evaluate("count(search({""ab"",""cd""},""bcde""))>0") ' True
```

Or with your sample:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Evaluate("count(search({""test"",""Book1""},""" & Me.Name & """))=0") Then
        MsgBox "NotOK"
    End If
End Sub
```